# Typo in help section > privileges

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, grammar

Under [Help Center > Privileges > Access Review Queues](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) there is a small typo in

```
educated on some aspect or our model
```

where the **or** should be replaced by **of**.

Additionally in the last section one can find

```
allowing you to complete review
```

where I would write **the review**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed in next build, watch for rev numbers `2013.11.11.1623` meta, `2013.11.11.1144` sites.

Comment: Complete codebase deploy just for grammar?

Comment: the alternative being going to each of the network sites (including metas) and edit the text?

Comment: For privilege pages there used to be central "template" here on meta that high rep users could edit themselves and then it would "propagate" to all other sites. Isn't there such mechanism in place now, only for moderators and devs?

Comment: there are default templates which are deployed with build, and can be overridden by the staff, but only separately per site.